# Monetization/advertizing components for desktop apps

Tags: windows, c#, advertising

I intend to write a Windows desktop program which will provide the user a few very useful system configuration options.

The application will be written in C# WPF (desktop, not universal app) and should have some in-app ads for monetizing purposes.

I was looking for an SDK like the [Microsoft advertising SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125365.aspx), but I could not find any for conventional WPF desktop applications (not universal). The Microsoft advertising SDK is also not compatible with WPF desktop.

Does anyone know software I can use to monetize my (non-metro WPF C#) desktop application by using ads?
Or is there a possibility to provide it via a website that displays the ads, when the installer is downloaded? This website should ideally be free, reliable and pay on time.

Comment: I'm not sure your second question is on-topic here. Sounds more like a question for Stack Overflow to me.

Comment: For me it seems more like this is not possible. But maybe I'm wrong with that.

Comment: Good that you asked such a question, I tried to find one too, but it seems there is no such tool

Comment: I am using TuneIn radio windows application. It has 2 versions, one that you can install from Microsoft store and second one that you can download the exe from their website and install. Both versions include Adsense. I know that Adsense is prohibited in desktop apps but how can this app use it? As far as I see, many people using the app. It is popular.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use google adsense? (or any other similar ad server) Get the program to fetch an ad from google's servers, put it in an html viewer and then add a click event that triggers the link for the ad to be started in the default browser... Not the most elegant solution but should do the trick...

Comment: Are you aware of any desktop program that actually does this? Thanks :-)

Comment: There is no such thing (since nobody develops for microsoft store anyways)  but i figured anyone could write something that would do this in just a few lines of code.

Comment: I have been searching the internet about adsense, too. But it is not allowed to put adsense ads into desktop applications. See [Ad placement policy of adsense](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en-AU)

Comment: To answer Nicolas Raoul's question: There are a few desktop programs containing ads, for example Skype (not sure but used to) or Spotify (free version). I guess Skype gets its ads from Microsoft itself, but I don't think that Spotify has its own advertising program.